# Python3 - selenium - Chrome : keyword instead of URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am exploring Selenium with Chromedriver and Python 3.4. I got curious and tried to do following

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("Cisco")
```

I gave a search keyword instead of URL to driver. It failed. I thought it will do a keyword search using google search engine. Am I doing something wrong?

I dont want to navigate to google.com and put keyword in search text box.
How can I directly search the keyword?

Any help or guidance will be very helpful.

Comment: it is not possible, to do search you need to go to google. Or you can go to the direct google url with query in it

Answer (score 1):

Just navigate directly to the results page. Use:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/#q=Cisco")
```